# How to get selected spinner value from list view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a listview with a textview and spinner which has same values for every spinner in the list.both values for textview and spinner are separately in xml files. how can i get selected spinner value for each row in the spinner..according to the relative textview..i m totally beginner to android ..

Answer (score 0):

In your `WhateverAdapter` add these methods:

```
public void setOnSpinnerItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener listener){
    this.mSpinnerItemSelectedListener = listener;
}
```

In your `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     //...

     viewHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mSpinnerItemClickListener);
     //.....
     return convertView;
}
```

Then in your `Activity` or wherever:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(Context....);
adapter.setOnSpinnerItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
myListView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: May i know what "mSpinnerItemSelectedListener" is?

Comment: It's class member that holds reference of the interface. :)