# Get spinner value from scroll able listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have a list view. Each list view contain spinner and I want to get the value of each spinner. But it doesn't work. It is ok if the listview is not scroll able.

```
private void checkPrice(){
        float total = 0;

        Log.d(TAG,"This is qty: "+ quantity);
        for (int i=0; i < mProductItems.size(); i++){
            View view = mListView.getChildAt(i);

            float eachTotal = 0;
            float discountAmount = 0;

            // Get Quantity
            Spinner getQtyView = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spQty);
            String getQty = getQtyView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Integer qty = Integer.parseInt(getQty);

            // Get Line item amount view
            TextView txvAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txvAmount);

            // Get product by view position
            OEDataRow eachProduct = (OEDataRow) mProductItems.get(i);

            Integer eachPrice = eachProduct.getInt("retail_price");

            // Check Discount
            if (eachProduct.getBoolean("promotion_disc")){
                float promo = (float) eachProduct.getInt("promotion_amount")/100;
                Log.d(TAG,"this is promo: "+promo);
                discountAmount = (float)( eachPrice * qty ) * promo;
            }else {
                discountAmount = 0;
            }

            eachTotal = (float)( eachPrice * qty ) - discountAmount;

            txvAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", eachTotal));

            Log.d(TAG, "Each Total: " + eachTotal);

            total = eachTotal + total;

            Log.d(TAG,"Total: "+ total);

        }
        btnCheckout.setText("Checkout: "+String.format("%.2f", total));
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289210/how-to-get-selected-spinner-value-from-list-view-in-android

Comment: Here I found the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248695/get-the-position-in-a-listview-of-a-spinner-and-get-its-selected-value

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. I'll solve like this.Try this. This is just example Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SpinnerAdapter ratingAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<String> listString;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listString = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        for(int listCount = 0; listCount < 20 ; listCount++){
            listString.add("ListCount"+listCount);
        }

        List<String> spinnerData = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listString.size(); i++) {
            spinnerData.add("MyTest="+i);
        }

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, spinnerData);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        fillAdapter();
    }

    private void fillAdapter() {
        ratingAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(ratingAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        Spinner spinner;
    }

    class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        Context context;
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> selectedItems  = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        public SpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.item_list_spinner_adaoter, listString);
            this.context = context;
        }

           public int getCount() {
                return listString.size();
            }
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                 return listString.get(position);
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_spinner_adaoter, null);
                holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
             if ( selectedItems.get( position ) != null ) {
                 holder.spinner.setSelection( selectedItems.get( position ) );
             }
            holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    selectedItems.put( position, arg2 );
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:transcriptMode="disabled" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


In item_list_spinner_adaoter.xml:
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```