# Get the position in a ListView of a Spinner and get its selected value

Tags: android, android-listview

I implemented an `ArrayAdapter` for my `ListView`:

```
public class CalcAMRListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AMRStateListEntry> implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public CalcAMRListAdapter(Context context, List<AMRStateListEntry> entries) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_calc_amr_fragment_row, entries);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AMRStateListEntry entry = this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calc_amr_fragment_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.spinnerActivity = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calc_amr_row_spinner_activity);
            viewHolder.spinnerHours = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calc_amr_row_spinner_hours);
            viewHolder.textViewPal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calc_amr_row_textview_pal);
            viewHolder.imageButtonDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calc_amr_row_button_delete);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String pal = null;

        switch (entry.getActivity()) {
        case 1: pal = "" + 0.95;
            break;
        case 2: pal = "" + 1.2;
            break;
        case 3: pal = "" + 1.5;
            break;
        case 4: pal = "" + 1.7;
            break;
        case 5: pal = "" + 1.9;
            break;
        case 6: pal = "" + 2.4;
            break;
        default: pal = "";
            break;
        }

        viewHolder.spinnerActivity.setSelection(entry.getActivity());
        viewHolder.spinnerActivity.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        viewHolder.spinnerHours.setSelection(entry.getHour());
        viewHolder.spinnerHours.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        viewHolder.textViewPal.setText(pal);
        viewHolder.imageButtonDelete.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_row);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

    private static class ViewHolder {
        Spinner spinnerActivity = null;
        Spinner spinnerHours = null;
        TextView textViewPal = null;
        ImageButton imageButtonDelete = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see each item of my `ListView` contains two `Spinner`. In the `onItemSelected` method i now need to get the position of the row in the `ListView` where the `Spinner` was used to select a value and i also need to differ between the two spinners in one row. My data model is the `AMRStateListEntry`. I need to set the selected values of the spinners inside my `AMRStateListEntry`.

How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the selected value of a Spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner)

Comment: I cant see where i can get the position of the row in the lisview from the link you posted. i know how i get the value from a spinner but first i need to get the correct spinner from the correct row in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewHolder.spinnerHours.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int positionInSpinner, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Create it like this instead. Then you set `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` the position to be `final`. Now you can use `final int position` inside your `onItemSelected`.

And do the same for your other `Spinner`